# Selenium elemento no visible Python

Tags: python, login, selenium

Estoy tratando de loguearme a un sitio con urgencia a travez de Selenium. Todos los sitios en los cuales intente loguearme pude menos este. Luego de poner esta parte del codigo me muestra un error Python 2.7:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 350, in send_keys
    'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 499, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 297, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.32.498537 (cb2f855cbc7b82e20387eaf9a43f6b99b6105061),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.6 x86_64)
```

Codigo:

```
# coding=utf-8


from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Martin/Desktop/chromedriver')
driver.get("https://car.com")
user= driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="onevideo_login_username"]')
user.send_keys("email")
```

Aca adjunto lo que inspecciono:

```html
<input type="text" id="onevideo_login_username" name="adaptv_email" data-i18n-placeholder="login.username" ng-model="models.login.email" class="ng-pristine ng-valid" placeholder="Username">
```

Como dije antes, realizando este mismo proceso pude loguearme en todos los sitios pero no entiendo porque en este no me deja.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Cuando un elemento no es Visible pero puedes conseguir el xpath y funciona, en una herramienta como [firepath](https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/firepath/), por ejemplo, el problema suele ser que el input está incluido en un iframe o algo parecido.

Si es así, tienes que cambiarte al frame correspondiente y despues buscar el elemento.

Comment: como se cambia el frame?? @j.barrio

Comment: driver.switchTo().frame("name", "id" or "element");